# Grep Search in Shell Script

Tags: shell, grep

Trying to implement a system which is based on shell script and PHP. Getting the string from PHP file and processing through shell scripts. 
Every time it's working except some time where strings are like : "/jobs?location_country=united+states&sort_by=cfml10%2cdesc&v_location=usa" 
grep for this command not working.

How to solve this?

Code is :

```
hcm=$(php largest.php "$file"_hcm_input.txt "$remove")
echo "$hcm"
grep "$hcm" "$file"_sorted.txt > "$file"_jobs.txt
```

Comment: Use single-quotes around that string, not double-quotes. Double-quotes don't esacpe the `&` which tells your shell that you want to execute the command in the background and cuts off the string. Or rather the rest of the string is treated as a new command, which of course fails.

Comment: Already tried with single quotes. Same result. Not able to search through grep. But in manual search , i mean, in the file ctrl+f I am able to get 366 matching.

Comment: Well, it's a good idea to post the script, so we know what you're actually talking about.

Comment: Added, whatever I want to have. That PHP file is returning the string which I need to search in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting lot hit and trial found out that this is not the issue with & = or + as i have checked individually

```
grep "=" s37_sorted.txt 
grep "&" s37_sorted.txt 
grep "+" s37_sorted.txt
```

Giving me output.

Exact reason was the case. So we need to find with case insensitive manner for that we have to follow the following code and parameter with grep is -i

```
hcm=$(php largest.php "$file"_hcm_input.txt "$remove")
echo "Highest Common String:"$hcm
grep -i "$hcm" "$file"_sorted.txt > "$file"_jobs.txt
```

Now it's showing me 366 records.

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -F` or `grep --fixed-strings` to tell grep to treat the argument as a fixed string rather than a regex.

Comment: Nope, it's not working. same null output after running the command grep --fixed-strings "/jobs?location_country=united+states&sort_by=cfml10%2cdesc&v_location=usa" s2_sorted.txt

Comment: and also same thing for the command grep -F "/jobs?location_country=united+states&sort_by=cfml10%2cdesc&v_location=usa" s2_sorted.txt

Answer (score 0):

As you have `&` in the string, even if you enclose it in single/double quotes it won't work.
In this case you have to escape `&`, using `\` like `\&`.

Comment: tried with this too, not working. grep "/jobs?location_country=united+states\&sort_by=cfml10%2cdesc\&v_location=usa" s2_sorted.txt

Comment: Found out that grep is not working when it contains = & and +

Comment: May i know the shell/envoriment you are using?

Comment: bash shell and ubuntu 18.0.4 LTS